# Loop through Wordpress API response errors

Tags: jquery, rest-api, api, json

I am having trouble parsing my AJAX response from my WordPress API that my hybrid mobile app is making. Below is (one of many ways I have tried to parse the response all of which have not worked):

```
     var $team_url = '/wp-json/wp/v2/team-post?_embed';
        $.ajax({
            url: $base_url + $team_url,
            async: true,
            dataType:'json',
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $.mobile.loading('show');
            },
            complete: function (wpdata) {
                $.mobile.loading('hide');

              // var data = jQuery.parseJSON(wpdata);

              //  var data = JSON.stringify(wpdata);

                //var items = '';
//THE LOOP BELOW SHOULD SHOW 10 POST IDS IN MY CONSOLE
                $.each(wpdata, function(index, post) {
                  console.log(post.id);
             });
           // $("#artist-list").append(items);
            },


    });
```

When I check my network tab I am seeing the JSON and it is returning 0-9 post of my custom post type "team-post" but when I try to access the individual data from the response I am not having any luck.

If it helps I can post the many errors I keep getting whenever I try something different.

Below I have added another way I tried to loop through it and the error I got.

```
$.each(wpdata.responseText, function(index, post) {
      console.log(post.id);
 });
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '31687' in [{"id":597,"date":"2019-12...
```

Comment: This does not sound like a WordPress issue, but what happens if you change `complete: function...` to `success: function...`

Comment: ```jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined``` is the error I get when using 'successs:'

Comment: There is no `length` in your code sample so that must be coming from something else, not the code shown here.